# How to Get Buffer for Road in Arcgis Android?

Tags: android, arcgis

I am developing one Application using `arcgis`. Here i want to implement buffer for both point and line Segments (road).

Here i successfully get buffer for point using this method

```
GeometryEngine.buffer(geometry1,mMapView.getSpatialReference(), meters, null)
```

where as for road if it is single Segment i am able draw buffer.I am unable to draw buffer for multiple Segments.

Please give me solution for this.I want like

my code 
[image]

```
 polygon = GeometryEngine.buffer(geometry1,
                mMapView.getSpatialReference(), meters, null);
        withingeometry = GeometryEngine.project(polygon,
                mMapView.getSpatialReference(),
                mMapView.getSpatialReference());    

  SimpleFillSymbol sls = new SimpleFillSymbol(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        sls.setAlpha(75);

        Graphic graphics= new Graphic(withingeometry,sls);
        buffergraphiclayer.addGraphic(graphics);
        mMapView.addLayer(buffergraphiclayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that should produce the result you want, both involving the [`GeometryEngine.union(Geometry[], SpatialReference)` method](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html):

1. Call `union` on an array of the `Geometry` objects you want to buffer to produce a single `Geometry`, and then call `buffer` on that single `Geometry`.
2. Call `buffer` on an array of the `Geometry` objects you want to buffer to produce a `Polygon` array, and then call `union` on that `Polygon` array.